# how to use image in ToggleButtons?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use ToggleButtons with two options using photos in jpg, is it possible?
I tried this code.

```
<const List<Widget> imgList = <Widget>[
  ImageIcon(AssetImage("lib/images/10x15.jpg"), size: 80),
  ImageIcon(AssetImage("lib/images/pk_sb.jpg"), size: 80),
  ImageIcon(AssetImage("lib/images/pk_sm.jpg"), size: 80),
];
...
       ToggleButtons(
                direction: vertical ? Axis.vertical : Axis.horizontal,
                onPressed: (int index) {
                  setState(() {
                    // The button that is tapped is set to true, and the others to false.
                    for (int i = 0; i < _selectedWeather.length; i++) {
                      _selectedWeather[i] = i == index;
                    }
                  });
                },
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                selectedBorderColor: Colors.blue[700],
                selectedColor: Colors.white,
                fillColor: Colors.blue[200],
                color: Colors.blue[400],
                isSelected: _selectedWeather,
                children: imgList,
              ),
...
```

I need to show the buttons with this image, but only two blue rectangles appear

[image]

If it is not possible to replace the icons how could I implement this?